# mimic 'Enter' Key press in Webtest using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, keyboard, webdriver, webtest

I want to mimic <kbd>Enter</kbd> being pressed in Webtest. I am using Selenium 2.3.1. I want to do it using WebDriver. I know that we can do this using Selenium RC, but I do not want to do it that way. Has anybody done this before? I am open to upgrade to Selenium 2.20.0 (latest).

Answer (score 5):

You can send an Enter key to an element. However, you can't press Enter to, say, confirm a download dialog.

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.id("damnit")); // obtain an element
elem.sendKeys(org.openqa.selenium.Keys.ENTER); // this sends an Enter key to the element
elem.sendKeys("hey" + org.openqa.selenium.Keys.ENTER); // this writes and then confirms by Enter
```